# Using rep function with nrow as frequency for different data frames in R

Tags: r, apply

If I have:

```
One <- c(rep("X",6),rep("Y",3),rep("Z",2))
Two <- c(rep("Blue",4),rep("Red",7))

Three <- c(rep("A",4),rep("B",6),rep("C",1))
Four <- c(rep("Green",5),rep("Black",6))

df1 <- cbind(One,Two)
df2 <- cbind(Three,Four)

df.final <- as.data.frame(rbind(df1,df2))


Month <- c(rep("January",nrow(df1)), rep("February",nrow(df2)))
cbind(Month,df.final)

      Month One   Two
1   January   X  Blue
2   January   X  Blue
3   January   X  Blue
4   January   X  Blue
5   January   X   Red
6   January   X   Red
7   January   Y   Red
8   January   Y   Red
9   January   Y   Red
10  January   Z   Red
11  January   Z   Red
12 February   A Green
13 February   A Green
14 February   A Green
15 February   A Green
16 February   B Green
17 February   B Black
18 February   B Black
19 February   B Black
20 February   B Black
21 February   B Black
22 February   C Black
```

Everything is dandy, but my question is for `Month <- c(rep("January",nrow(df1)), rep("February",nrow(df2)))` I am going to have 12 data frames and want to great a vector with the freq of each month corresponding the nrows for each of 12 dataframes I have. Intuitively, I would think something like this would work:

```
lapply(c(months*),function(x) rep(x,nrow(c(list of 12 dataframes))##pseudo code
```

I am trying to avoid doing `Months <- c(rep("Jan",nrow(jan.df)),rep("Feb",nrow(feb.df)),...,rep("Dec",nrow(def.df)))`
In the end I am going to `cbind` this vector to an `rbind` of all the month dataframes. Just like in the example except there's only two months there.

Answer (score 1):

do you not just want a table of months from each data frame `table(df$month)` ? This would give you a count of how many times each month appears in a data frame.

```
a <- data.frame(rep("january",10))
names(a) <- c("Month")
b <- a
c <- a
df_list <- list(a,b,c)
sapply(df_list,function(x)table(x$Month))

!> sapply(df_list,function(x)table(x$Month))
 january january january
      10      10      10
```

If you want the frequency,how many the month appears over the total of rows, you can just do:

```
sapply(df_list,function(x)table(x$Month)/nrow(x))

!> sapply(df_list,function(x)table(x$Month)/nrow(x))
 january january january
       1       1       1
```